# What is the resume principles of AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am learning AFNetworking ,and i have a problem.

I create a download task and resume it.
 Then i suspend the task , this task has been paused.
Last i resume the task ,this task continues to download.

What is the resume principles  of **AFNetworking** ?

Comment: The principles is implemented by AFNetworking or urlsessiontask?

Answer (score 0):

The principles of AFNetworking 2.x versions is recording the request's ETag and resource data offset, when you suspend the task. While you resume the task，the AFNetworking could pass the both value to server. If the resource data is not modified, the response continue to receive that be not downloaded data from server last.

Comment: AFNetworking 2.x versions recording the request‘s ETAG and resource data offset   or the nsurlsession recording these?